# NAT separate firewall or other security tools

Tags: firewalls, router

It's a conceptual question:

Suppose i want to separate `NAT` and `firewall`, can it help to my security?

INTERNET >>>> NAT >>>> Firewall >>> MyNetwork

Comment: Are you talking about using NAT overloaded as a security measure?

Comment: yes, want to impelement defense in depth.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would make much of a difference. NAT has nothing to do with security and the firewall should be your primary defense.

Having a device provide both firewall and NAT services isn't a security risk by itself. The only potential security risk would be the software and configuration of the device. Since there are so many vendors/products on the market and questions about products is disallowed, this cannot be answered anyways.